# How to remove ' ' in a python list

Tags: python

I load a csv.file where the dataset comes in the form ('5.5','4.3'...)

How can I remove the ' '?

I've tried with replace, but it doesn't seem to work with the '.

Thanks!

It's basically:

```
 ['1'] => [1]
```

Comment: please upload your attempts so we can help

Comment: `row = [float(i) for i in row]`

Comment: @melgart Because this is such a poor question that answering it will probably get him downvoted.

Comment: @melgart: it's more because the question isn't fully specified. I don't know if OP has a "row" variable. That means that any suggestions I make are just that - suggestions, or hints that __could__ work, but are not necessarily guaranteed to, because OP's code may not be structured the way I assume it is

Comment: cool, thanks to you both. helps me with my answers.

Comment: Thanks! I'll use the float function

Comment: @Jensgrønborg Note if you use the float function, be sure what you're trying to turn into a float is actually a number. If you do something like `float('a')`, it'll throw an exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are working with `float` data type, the following list builder code (as previously pointed in the comments) should work.

```
row = [float(i) for i in row]
```